# Post a UIImage to the web

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, load, uiimage

I'm just starting with the xcode business and so far so good, except for this tiny detail: I don't know how to **post a UIImage to the web**. I've been trying everything for the last 3 days (read and queried a lot) without success. The answer, I think is under my nose, still... no luck.

I leave here the code I wrote (either in objective-c and php): it doesn't work at all!! No image is uploaded. Please, could someone help me?

**//objective-C**

```
NSData *theData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo.image);  
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.testes01.com/newsie/receberprofilephoto.php";  
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];  
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];  
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];  
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];  
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];  
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];  
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"iphoneimage.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:theData]];  
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
[request setHTTPBody:body];  
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];  
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**//PHP**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"][tmp_name], "fotosprofile/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works, the only thing wrong was not CHMODing the folder to 777 so you can read & write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for image uploading on a web
self.image is my uiimage object which i have made property and synthesize it.Get your image in self.image then:-

```
NSData *imagedata=[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image)];
    NSString *base64string=[imagedata base64EncodedString];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.testes01.com/newsie/receberprofilephoto.php"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:base64string forKey:@"imagedata"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
    NSLog(@"responseStatusString %@",[request responseString]);
```

I hope this might help you!!!!

Comment: Hi @Jenifer,  Thanks for your prompt reply. Unfortunately I also tried with ASIHTTPRequest Library too, but it didn't work either.   Nevertheless, I noticed a couple of hours ago that the server where I post my images didn't allow me to upload images programmatically; I tried chmod 777 but I had no permission. So, I called them and solved my problem. Bottom line, The code is okay. For what is worth, thanks for your reply and, maybe for prosperity, the code stays here.  JUST REMEMBER folks, in case the code doesn't work, the problem can be with your folder or file permission.  Bye!